# Not a managed type: class com.springboot.entities.User

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

The Error says Unable to create bean named with user Repository .not  a a managed type com.user .entities
Tried with multiple component such enablejparepository.entityscan still it doesn't work

```
package com.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.springboot.dao.UserRepository;
import com.springboot.entities.User;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DataApplication.class, args);
        UserRepository userRepository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("prashant");
        user.setCity("vikhroli");
        user.setStatus("java programming");
        User user2 = userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println(user2);
 }
}
```

### This is the main Application class

```
package com.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.springboot.dao.UserRepository;
import com.springboot.entities.User;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DataApplication.class, args);
        UserRepository userRepository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("prashant");
        user.setCity("vikhroli");
        user.setStatus("java programming");
        User user2 = userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println(user2);
 }
}
```

### This the repository class

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository\<User, Integer\> {

}
```

```
 package com.springboot.entities;

      import javax.persistence.Entity;
      import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
      import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
      import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String city;
    public String status;
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public User(int id, String name, String city, String status) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.status = status;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", city=" + city + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

### This is the entity class

```
      spring.datasource.name=world
      spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:/pops
      spring.datasource.username=root
      spring.datasource.password=root
      spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

### The Error log

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.springboot.dao.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.springboot.entities.User

Comment: Are you using Spring-boot in version `>= 3`? If so: Spring-boot switched from `javax.persistence` to `jakarta.persistence`.

Comment: Did you google the error. Here's one link which you can check : https://www.java67.com/2023/04/how-to-fix-not-managed-type-exception.html

Answer (score -1):

**First:** you can try that

`@Repository public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> { }`
with `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.springboot.dao")` anotation with springboot app class.

**Second:** you can check `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency  at your pom.xml

**Third:** You can try use Long for id. I think that it is better practice.

Comment: Adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` isn't needed for a Spring Boot application, in fact it will even disable parts of the auto configuration if you add it. The same for `@Repository` on a Sprng Data interface repository it doesn't add anything but overhead.

Comment: Unfortunately you are wrong my friend some cases springboot cant see the repositories so , sometimes this annotation can be needed because of the directory or intelij ide, also its  doesnt  disable autoconfiguration  just enable jparepo

Comment: No I'm not wrong. If it is an IDE problem the problem is different and the solution isn't adding that annotation, and yes it will disable parts of the JPA auto configuration (Or more precise Spring Data JPA auto configuration).

Answer (score -1):

Also you can try adding
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.base.*")

annotation to your main springboot class file

eg in your case:

@EnableJpaRepositories("com.springboot.entities*") // path of entity package
@SpringBootApplication
public class DataApplication {`enter code here`
//
}

Comment: Adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` isn't needed for a Spring Boot application, in fact it will even disable parts of the auto configuration if you add it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).